# R shiny observeEvent not working in function in module

Tags: r, module, shiny

Thank you in advance for your help. I've tried to boil my issue down into as simple of an app as I could construct. I have a function sliderResetInput that calls an observeEvent and returns some UI elements. I can use sliderResetInput outside of a module (will demonstrate below), but I cannot use it inside a module. I thought this was an issue with a wrapping a namespace around my inputs, but I think the ID's all check out here. What's going on? As a note, while this construction seems needlessly complicated for this app, I need the structure for a much larger app.

This works:

```
library(shiny) # Version 1.0.5

sliderResetInput = function(id, input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input[[paste0(id, "_reset_slider")]], 
               updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = paste0(id, "_slider"), value = c(0, 10)))

  out = list(
    sliderInput(inputId = paste0(id, "_slider"), label = "Slider", min = 0, max = 10, value = c(0, 10)),
    actionButton(inputId = paste0(id, "_reset_slider"), label = "Reset slider")
  )

  return(out)
}


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  getSliders = reactive(sliderResetInput(id = "test1", input, output, session))

  output$sliders = renderUI(getSliders())

  observeEvent(input$browser, browser())
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput(outputId = "sliders"),
  actionButton(inputId = "browser", "Click me to go into browser()")
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T))
```

With the same sliderResetInput() function, this does NOT work:

```
library(shiny) # Version 1.0.5

sliderResetInput = function(id, input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input[[paste0(id, "_reset_slider")]], 
               updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = paste0(id, "_slider"), value = c(0, 10)))

  out = list(
    sliderInput(inputId = paste0(id, "_slider"), label = "Slider", min = 0, max = 10, value = c(0, 10)),
    actionButton(inputId = paste0(id, "_reset_slider"), label = "Reset slider")
  )

  return(out)
}


myModuleUI = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)

  tagList(
    uiOutput(outputId = ns("sliders"))
  )
}



myModule = function(input, output, session) {
  ns = session$ns

  getSliders = reactive(sliderResetInput(id = ns("test1"), input, output, session))

  output$sliders = renderUI(getSliders())
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(myModule, id = "A")
  observeEvent(input$browser, browser())
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  myModuleUI(id = "A"),
  actionButton(inputId = "browser", "Click me to go into browser()")
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T))
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This structure certainly doesn't make any sense to me. Why not put the `observeEvent` into the *server* part of the module and the inputs in the `moduleUI`?

Comment: @GyD, basically, I have to make an arbitrary amount of these kinds of inputs, so I need a function like sliderResetInput() to loop through and it is important for me to be able to save the list returned from the function.

Comment: Is there any functionality you can't achieve with [this format](https://gist.github.com/dgyurko/dceaf1514e7f5cdbeee1f183bf11a0e9)? You can easily try it out via `runGist("https://gist.github.com/dgyurko/dceaf1514e7f5cdbeee1f183bf11a0e9")`

Answer (score 2):

You have to prefix the ids of the widgets only. That is:

```
sliderResetInput = function(id, NSid, input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input[[paste0(id, "_reset_slider")]], {
    updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = paste0(id, "_slider"), value = c(0, 10))
  })

  out = list(
    sliderInput(inputId = paste0(NSid, "_slider"), label = "Slider", min = 0, max = 10, value = c(0, 10)),
    actionButton(inputId = paste0(NSid, "_reset_slider"), label = "Reset slider")
  )

  return(out)
}
```

and

```
  getSliders = reactive(sliderResetInput(id = "test1", NSid = ns("test1"), input, output, session))
```